# Rails Heroku starting Unicorn with Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I am trying to run a Rails app on Heroku using Unicorn.

I realized this morning that Heroku was starting Webrick instead of Unicorn.

I believe the problem was that the "Procfile" shows uppercase P on my iMac, but when I send to GIT it ends up lowercase.  I fixed the case and sent it to Github.  I view on Github and the case is correct.

Now my issue is I can't tell if Unicorn is running or not.  How can I tell?  What should I look for?

Thanks for the help!

PS -- Also, how can I tell for sure that the Git repository on Heroku has the Uppercase "Procfile"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `heroku ps -a <your_app_name>` to see your running processes on Heroku. If you want to see the files you have on remote, either clone from Heroku remote or run `heroku run bash -a <your_app_name>` and then type `ls`.